# Equivalence of two definitions of "projective dimension of a complex"

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I read two different definition of projective dimension of a complex $M$
The first (given by foxby) is: $$\operatorname{pd}_R M= \inf_P \sup\{\, n\,|\,P_n\neq 0\,\}$$
And the second definition is: the projective dimension of $M$ is the smallest integer $n>-1$ with the property $\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(M,-)=0$. If no such integer exists then it is $\infty$.

Are those two definition the same? How to prove it?

Comment: I didn’t understand first definition.. Can you make it clearer..

Comment: Hi, please don't use subject areas as question titles. Those belong in tags, usually. Actually type something that relates to the question you're asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions agree provided you are only interested in $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(M,N)$ vanishing for all $R$-modules, rather than all $R$-complexes.

Let 
$$\text{pd}_{R}(M) = \inf_{P}\sup\{n:P_{n}\neq0\}$$
denote  the projective dimension of the complex $M$, where the $P$ runs over all DG-projective complexes quasi-isomorphic to $M$. This is your first definition.

We then have the following (slightly abbreviated) theorem from Avramov and Foxby's paper *Homological dimensions of unbounded complexes*:

> **Theorem 2.4.P** For a complex $M$ of $R$-modules, the following are equivalent:
>
> - $\text{pd}_{R}(M)\leq n$;
> - $\text{Ext}_{R}^{i}(M,N)=0$ for $i>n-\inf(N)$ and any complex of $R$-modules $N$;
> - $\text{Ext}_{R}^{n+1}(M,N)=0$ for any $R$-module $N$ and $H_{i}(M)=0$ for $i>n+1$.

This then gives you the equivalence between your definitions, or at least the relationship between Ext-vanishing and projective dimensions.